# NLog avoid repeated lines and set delta time

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, milliseconds

I am using Nlog and couldn't find the features here below.
Of course I could make them by myself but since NLog usually takes care of all needs perhaps might have all this built-in.

---

**Delta seconds between each entry**

I have the layout as
"[${date:format=dd.MM.yyyy HH\:mm\:ss.fff}] (${level:uppercase=true}): ${message}"
So that I get something like:

```
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.667] (INFO): --- 20210520_1153 Starting ---
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784] (INFO): *.cfg not found going for TRIAL LICENCE
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784] (INFO): Reg Hive found. Verifying
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784] (INFO): Key length = 3
```

Is it possible to automaticalla add delta time? so like here below

```
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.667 - 0.000] (INFO): --- 20210520_1153 Starting ---
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784 - 0.117] (INFO): *.cfg not found going for TRIAL LICENCE
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784 - 0.000] (INFO): Reg Hive found. Verifying
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784 - 0.000] (INFO): Key length = 3
```

---

**Avoid repeated lines (at will)**

```
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.667] (INFO): AAA
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784] (INFO): AAA
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784] (INFO): AAA
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784] (INFO): AAA
```

to become something like

```
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.667] (INFO): AAA
...
```

And to be able to extend that also to more than one level

```
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.667] (INFO): AAA
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784] (INFO): BBB
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784] (INFO): AAA
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784] (INFO): BBB
```

to become

```
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.667] (INFO): AAA
[20.05.2021 11:53:33.784] (INFO): BBB
...
```

That would save a lot of chars

Thanks in advance

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `${processtime}` to see time since program was started. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Processtime-Layout-Renderer (Useful for seeing deltas).

You can use `WhenRepeated`-filter to block duplicate logevents. But it is better to avoid doing repeated logging, when possible (And ensure logging-rules have been properly configured). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WhenRepeated-Filter

Comment: Thanks for helping. Let's see both point: (1.) I would like to know delta time between lines and not from the beginning.  (2.) Please could you elaborate this concept? I am not clear whether it is better that I handle that matter or leave to NLog to do it.

Comment: For first point then I just use my eyes to see the delta between two times. For second point then `whenRepeated` is only used as last-resort where the application cannot be modified.

Comment: For the 1st point my eyes are not enough when I need to examinate thousand or millions of entries. And not even my brain. As for the 2nd please confirm what I understand aka that it is better not to implement any char saving strategy IN THE LONG for that will slow down the log writing process. Better act differently and choose wisely what messages to direct to the log.

Comment: @Patrick For collecting application-metrics in a large scale systems, then I would probably have dedicated metric-collectors that saves in a time-series-database and then have a Grafana-Dashbord (Instead of depending on log-statements). And yes if you have the ability to adjust the application, then it is better to remove duplicate logging, instead of filtering afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

These features (especially the second) would require a continuous parsing of the content of the existing log file, which is going to significantly impact performance.
I doubt NLog will contain a re-parsing feature, and even if it did, I doubt it'd be a good idea to use it.

In both cases, it is significantly easier to preprocess the writing of the log message than it is to retroactively have to re-parse the log and figure out of the current log message should be written or not.

Comment: Well yes but for the repeated lines exclusion you would only have to store the last written line (or more lines) and not to write it if it is the same. That is what I do in my code. Having it automatically done would be great

Comment: @Patrick And store those lines where, precisely? Don't forget that multiple loggers can write to the same log file. A single logger instance has no way to guarantee that the log hasn't changed inbetween writing different log messages. This is why it makes little sense from NLog's perspective. From _your_ perspective, however, you might have guaranteed that there is only one source logger for a given log file. NLog can't blindly account for that, nor arbitrary logic. It's genuinely easier to write it yourself than to figure out how to configure NLog's arbitrary implementation of such a feature.

Comment: You are right, merci! In my logic I have one main log. Additionally there might be some other logs. So no writing to the same log. When I create a logger I create a string in which i put the last written log entry. I didn't know that in this NL could have several logger writing to the same log. Any chance for the delta time? This could be done even in multi log logic